# Short-time work for professional football players

Tags: germany, workplace, sport

In Germany, a lot of people are currently doing "short-time work" right now which is partly compensated by the state or state-controlled insurances.

I heard that some employees of professional football clubs doing short-time work as well, but I never heard that professional football players were sent into short-time work. I wonder why this is the case because they don't have much to do right now and it would possibly save millions for some clubs.

So, my question: Is it legally possible to use short-time work (as legally defined in Germany) for professional football players?

Comment: This will depend on the details of their contract. Their have to be "sozialversicherungspflichtig beschäftigt" for short-time work.

Comment: Do DE pro "football" (soccer) players make the insane kind of money that USA pro "football" (rugby-ish) players make?  Generally when you're in the mad-money salaries, the social safety net falls away [like gantries away from a launching rocket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2z1LqJoYcs).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica no - top flight professional soccer players make considerably more than US NFL players.